# Android - Executing Asynctask in Activity

Tags: android, android-asynctask, static-methods

I have my login. The user types his username and password in EditText and press onClick login button.

```
public void onClick(View v) {

    String username = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.typeUsername)).getText().toString();
    String password = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.typePassword)).getText().toString();
    Controller handler = new Controller(getBaseContext());


    if (!username.equals("") || !password.equals("")) {
        //new LoginTask().execute(((EditText)findViewById(R.id.typeUsername)).getText().toString(),
         //       ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.typePassword)).getText().toString());
       LoginTask load = new LoginTask(context);
       load.execute();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please fill in all fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }
}
```

Now when the login button is clicked. It executes LoginTask in the same class.

In the LoginTask when the login button is clicked a dialog should show, and in the background the user input is checked with the SQL. executeLog is a method in my DatabaseHelper it is a rawQuery to the SQL checking if username and password matches. saveLogin() is another method in my sharedpref class that saves the username and password in sharedPreference.

My issue is how can I execute? LoginTask properly in the Login class? Do i need to pass anything? What should I use in LoginTask instead of getApplicationContext

Comment: Yes that is true. If you hadn't deleted your previous post I would have explained everything to you, but when I tried to post my answer you had already deleted the question... Don't post the same question multiple times. It is highly frowned upon... To summarize: you cannot use `Context` references in your task. This is exactly what creates memory leaks.

Comment: @XaverKapeller I apologise for this. I am new to Java. How can I fix my issue so that my code data is passed correctly?

Comment: Use `WeakReference` if you really need to have a reference to a `Context` or `Activity` in your task. With proper null checks this will prevent the creation of memory leaks.

Comment: @XaverKapeller Ive never handle weakreference can you look at my code and provide weakReference and execute my intent

Comment: See my answer for an example.

Comment: @XaverKapeller I have updated the code and dont understand how I will start my intent and if the Context is null do I just executeLog() or do I have to do another statement, can you update your answer and mold it to my code?

Comment: Ask a new question, show us all the relevant code that has to do with the login, explain the exact problem and why it isn't working and then we might be able to help you.

Answer (score 3):

The correct way to use a `Context` reference in your `AsyncTask` is like this:

```
private static class ExampleTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    private final WeakReference<Context> contextReference;

    private ExampleTask(Context context) {
        this.contextReference = new WeakReference<Context>(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        final Context context = this.contextReference.get();
        if(context != null) {
            // Inside this if you can safely use the context variable
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);

        final Context context = this.contextReference.get();
        if(context != null) {
            // Inside this if you can safely use the context variable
        }
    }
}
```

What the `WeakReference` does is it allows the garbage collector to destroy the `Activity` or `Context` even though your `AsyncTask` still has a reference to it and as such prevents the creation of memory leaks. If you want to use the `Context` inside your `AsyncTask` you need to call `get()` on the `WeakReference` like in the example above and perform a null check. If the `Context` you get from `get()` is not null you can safely use it.

Comment: Okay I will try and right this for my code and will update my code for any errors when I compile

Comment: Can you show how Im going to use all my methods? and reference the object used to check the user input matches with data in SQL database. How will I execute my intent?

Comment: No I cannot. How am I supposed to know what your methods do? I cannot fix things I know nothing about. And I cannot know what exactly the problem is if you don't explain it. For each different problem you should ask a new question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I have updated my code, how can I call? or execute my LoginTask? in my Login Activity? passing the username and pass

Comment: I cannot and will not solve every little problem for you. You should really learn a little bit more about Java and Android in general before you try writing an app.

Answer (score 1):

Your `LoginTask` is declared as static class, so you don't have acces to instance of `Login`. Althrough you are trying to access `Intent log` member.

Comment: I am new to Java programming, how can I call intent to start my MiainActivity

Answer (score 0):

LoginTask is declared static and it has not access to the outer environment. So neither `Intent` log or `getApplicationContext()` are visible from your `AsyncTask`. Also notice that your AsyncTask try to access not-intialized class member. E.g  `Controller handler;` in the AsyncTask's scope, is never intialized. When `doInBackground` will be executed it will cause a `NPE`

Comment: How can I fix this? sorry I am new to Java. Do i initalized all of my database controllers and instaces of classes that I need to execute my code into LoginTask too?